# Is it possible to set a global dispatcher for the built-in `fetch()` in Node?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, undici

You can pass a dispatcher *to* `fetch()` in Node:

```
import { Agent } from 'undici';

const response = await fetch(url, {
  dispatcher: new Agent(/* ... */),
});
```

And you can set a *global* dispatcher if you're using `undici` on its own:

```
import { Agent, fetch, setGlobalDispatcher } from 'undici';

setGlobalDispatcher(new Agent(/* ... */));
const response = await fetch(url);
```

But how would I go about obtaining the `setGlobalDispatcher()` function that's bound to the global dispatcher the *built-in* instance of `fetch()` that Node 18+ uses? Surely using a `setGlobalDispatcher()` function from a version of `undici` that *I* install will not be the same one.

Comment: That would be a terrible idea, exactly because it would change how `fetch` works globally, which would affect not just your own code, but also its use by _any_ other code that's a dependency of a dependency of a dependency. In your second codeblock, `setGlobalDispatcher` only changes the behaviour of the `fetch` that you imported from `undici`, it does _not_ change the regular fetch API.

Comment: Oh, that's not even close to my most terrible idea @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I have way more where that came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this discussion: https://github.com/nodejs/undici/discussions/2167#discussioncomment-6239415 it can be achieved by the following:

`globalThis[Symbol.for('undici.globalDispatcher.1')] = yourDispatcher;`

However I agree with Mike Pomax that this isn't a great idea. A better design would be to wrap `fetch` with your own local library, that overrides the dispatcher as you please. Then import that to use.